# Android to Oracle, Database Access and Manipulation

Tags: android, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Hello I'm working with Android and Oracle database. This is the scenario : I want to connect my Android client to insert a value to the table and and also retrieve the value from the same table in oracle database.

My working environment are :

1.Eclipse JUNO

2.JDK 1.7

3.ojdbc driver 6

4.ojdbc driver 14

5.Oracle Express 11g

So far what I've tried using

1. OJDBC driver 6
   I got `05-24 08:29:47.206: E/dalvikvm(364): Could not find class 'javax.management.MBeanServer', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.registerMBeans`
2. OJBDC driver 14 I got this `05-17 10:41:06.846: E/dalvikvm(456): Could not find class 'oracle.security.pki.OracleWallet', referenced from method oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getSecretStoreCredentials`

But when I try to code in pure Java with these following code which is same in android, I can successfully insert the value to the table

```
try
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", "SYSTEM", "radit");
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        st.execute("INSERT INTO NAMA VALUES ('RADITYA KURNIANTO')");
        st.close();
        conn.close();
        System.out.println("Query Success");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then, my questions are :

1. What is the perfect environment configuration to make the android code work? In this case is the right jdbc driver.
2. Then after getting the correct configuration, how to solve the error above?

If you suggest me to use Oracle Mobile Data server, please give a great tutorial on how to make it works in Android. Thanks.